# Camera intent destroy/change relative layout and table layout

Tags: android

In my application i am calling camera intent and capturing image successfully.
But after finishing of camera intent, it comes to actual activity it destroy/change complete layout(Which is relative and table layout).Here is the images of before and after calling of camera intent.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bcf1876dbc.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bcf1876dbc.png)
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/edca05b5d8.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/edca05b5d8.png)

when i type anything in editText box then all layout shown normally.
Here is the my code:-

'

```
<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
 android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/new_name_txt"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_column="1" android:text="@string/user_name"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
 <EditText android:id="@+id/new_name_edit"
  android:layout_width="160dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/new_user_id_txt"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_column="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:text="@string/new_user_id" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
 <EditText android:id="@+id/new_user_id_edit"
  android:layout_width="160dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>


<TableRow android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/user_name_admin_txt"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_column="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:text="User Name" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
 <EditText android:id="@+id/user_name_admin_edit"
  android:layout_width="160dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/user_paas_admin_txt"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_column="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:text="Password" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
 <EditText android:id="@+id/user_pass_admin_edit"
  android:layout_width="160dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="true" android:password="true" />
</TableRow>



<TableRow android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/pharam_id_txt"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_column="1" android:text="@string/pharam_id"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

 <Spinner android:id="@+id/pharm_id_spinner"
  android:layout_width="178dip" android:layout_height="55dip"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:prompt="@string/hiv_pharma" />

</TableRow>
```

'

Comment: That's messed up, man.  Are you on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: You should drop using TableLayout and use a combination of RelativeLayouts and LinearLayouts. TableLayout makes your life harder in many ways.